# Como obter o valor bootstrap toggle true ou false?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Tem um código:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            Checkbox One
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            Checkbox Two
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
            Toggle One
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"/>
            Toggle Two
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Como faço para obter se é `true` ou `false`, usando `Js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) com [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) no evento de carregamento do [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) e no evento [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) do elemento.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
      $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
    });
    $('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $('#toggle-event').prop('checked'));
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" id="toggle-event" />

<div id="console-event"></div>
```

***Referencias:***

- [jQuery - prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [JavaScript HTML DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)
- [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 1):

Selecione a `div` e o `input`, como de costume, com `id` ou afim. E para saber se está selecionado, basta usar `.checked`:

```js
$('#toggle1 input:checkbox').change(function(){
 console.log("toogle one:", this.checked); // ou $(this).prop('checked')
})
$('#toggle2 input:checkbox').change(function(){
 console.log("toogle two:", this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            Checkbox One
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"/>
            Checkbox Two
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="toggle1">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" checked="checked" />
            Toggle One
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="toggle2">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"/>
            Toggle Two
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default"/>
    </div>
</form>
```